# Simple CSS tabs - need to break border on active tab

Tags: css, tabs

I want to create a very simple tab style that looks like this:

```
  _____   _____   _____
_|_____|_|     |_|_____|______________
```

So basically there is a horizontal border on the bounding box that breaks for the active tab. I'm using a basic list, with the following CSS, but the outer border always appears over the individual tabs. I've tried various positioning and z-index as well to no avail.

```
ul.tabHolder {
    overflow: hidden;
    clear: both;
    margin: 1em 0;
    padding: 0;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #666;
}
ul.tabHolder li {
    list-style: none;
    float: left;
    margin: 0 3px -1px; /* -1 margin to move tab down 1px */
    padding: 3px 8px;
    background-color: #444;
    border: 1px solid #666;
    font-size: 15px;
}
ul.tabHolder li.active {
    background-color: #944;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #944;
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try [this solution](http://css.maxdesign.com.au/listamatic/horizontal05.htm) by Eric Meyer.

**Content below copied from the site to ensure the answer is still valid if the site closes, changes or breaks.**

```css
#navlist {
  padding: 3px 0;
  margin-left: 0;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #778;
  font: bold 12px Verdana, sans-serif;
}

#navlist li {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  display: inline;
}

#navlist li a {
  padding: 3px 0.5em;
  margin-left: 3px;
  border: 1px solid #778;
  border-bottom: none;
  background: #DDE;
  text-decoration: none;
}

#navlist li a:link {
  color: #448;
}

#navlist li a:visited {
  color: #667;
}

#navlist li a:hover {
  color: #000;
  background: #AAE;
  border-color: #227;
}

#navlist li a#current {
  background: white;
  border-bottom: 1px solid white;
}
```

```html
<div id="navcontainer">
  <ul id="navlist">
    <li id="active"><a href="#" id="current">Item one</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Item two</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Item three</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Item four</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Item five</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

> ABOUT THE CODE
>   Some lists within the Listamatic site had to be modified so that they could work on Listamatic's simple list model. When in doubt, use the external resource first, or at least compare both models to see which one suits your needs.

Comment: In the end I didn't have to change my code a whole lot, but this page helped me work it out.

Comment: I was punching my head off trying to find out why #navlist border was not wrapping the element, as css borders are always added outer to the element. It appears that the whole trick is due to the `font` property, I don't know how tf : https://jsfiddle.net/p9goxfbu/1/. If you remove it, or even change `font-family` to `serif`, a border bottom appears below the active tab. That should definitely not be the accepted answer

Comment: The UL and LI elements in this example were not necessary, here's a reduced version https://jsfiddle.net/ao2f8mnj/1/

Answer (score 3):

```css
.tab {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: #aaa;
  padding: 4px;
  border: 1px solid #888;
  border-bottom: none;
  
  position: relative;
  bottom:-1px;
  z-index: -1;
}

.tab-body {
  position: relative;
  height: 100px;
  width: 200px;
  padding: 4px;
  background-color: #ccc;
  border: 1px solid #888;
  z-index: 1;
}

.tab.active {
  background-color: #ccc;
  z-index: 2;
}
```

```html
<div class="tab tab1">Tab 1</div>
<div class="tab tab2 active">Tab 2</div>
<div class="tab tab3">Tab 3</div>

<div class="tab-body">Tab Body</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Changing your existing code as little as possible - try `display: inline-block` for the `li` tags, with the border on a `.menu` container `div`:

```
.menu {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #666;
}
ul.tabHolder {
    overflow: hidden;
    margin: 1em 0 -2px;
    padding: 0;
}
ul.tabHolder li {
    list-style: none;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0 3px;
    padding: 3px 8px 0;
    background-color: #444;
    border: 1px solid #666;
    font-size: 15px;
}
ul.tabHolder li.active {
    background-color: #944;
    border-bottom-color: #944;
}
```

HTML used to illustrate (added div at bottom to show blending of active tab into div colour):

```
<div class="menu">
    <ul class="tabHolder">
        <li>Menu 1</li>
        <li class="active">Menu 2</li>
        <li>Menu 3</li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div style="background-color: #944; height: 1em">
```

Comment: ...or Eric Meyer's solution, as posted by ghoppe while I was writing this :-)

Comment: Looks better if you set the `margin-bottom` on `ul.tabHolder` to `-1px` instead of `-2px` - http://jsfiddle.net/mrPAE/

Comment: Depends on the browser - in FF 3.6.3 (OS X) 1px doesn't hide the bottom border. Meyer's solution seems cleanest.

Comment: It occurred to me as I was reading this that there is a tab menu right above these answers… the css looks similar to Meyer's tabs. Maybe inspect the css of this very page to get ideas. :)